# Select within two dates, where the second one is not defined

Tags: sql, date

I need to do a query between two dates, and this is easy, but how can I select if, for example the date_end is: `0000-00-00` (that means no end)
something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news WHERE NOW() BETWEEN data_start  
/* and if data_end > 0000-00-00 */ AND data_end
```

thanks.

Comment: Don't use `BETWEEN` for DATE datatypes. Use `x >= start AND x < end`. This is because dates are not discrete values, but continuous values. If you want to cover the first three day in January `BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-03'` will only work if the date field *never* includes a time component. `x >= '2012-01-01' AND x < '2012-01-04'` will always cover the whole of the three days regardless of whether the data is accurate to a day, hour, minute or pico-second. *[Also, consider using NULL to mean no date (to be explicit that there is no date), or '9999-12-31' so you don't need extra logic]*

Answer (score 2):

Why can you just do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news 
WHERE data_start <= NOW() AND (data_end >=NOW() OR data_end ='0000-00-00')
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `0000-00-00` to represent no end date, you should make this field nullable, and set the value to `NULL`. This makes a lot more logical sense than setting the `end_date` to an early value.

Just because no `news` record will end at `0000-00-00` doesn't make it correct to use this as a "no end" value. For example if in the future you need to work out the average date range of news, using `0000-00-00` is going to skew your results.

You could update all the current records by doing:

```
UPDATE news
SET end_date=NULL
WHERE end_date='0000-00-00'
```

Then you can run a query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM news
WHERE NOW()>=date_start
AND (NOW()<date_end OR date_end IS NULL)
```

If you don't have the ability to change this, then [@Arion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10397336/370103) is a good "[hack fix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge)"

Comment: +1 : Or use a date to represent "eternity", such as `'9999-12-31'`, or whatever the maximum date is for that particular datatype / RDBMS. That way no extra logic is needed at all. *[And the minimum date allowable for "epcoh" instead of NULL in the start_date value.]*

Comment: @Dems I would still class this as bad practice as a "date range" value would be skewed. See my edit.

Comment: That's debatable and depends on the stated functionality and requirements. By which I mean, if the end date is NULL, the "true duration" of the date range is infinity, which is going to skew any averaging any way.  *[To inifinity, in fact.]*

Comment: @Dems Thats true, I suppose it would depend on the individual functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news 
WHERE 
  data_start<=NOW()
  AND (data_end='0000-00-00' OR data_end>=NOW())
```

Comment: yes, think you're right, it's correct, thanks to everybody for helping me

Answer (score 0):

This should work, though you may want to check the date format on your server:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news WHERE NOW() BETWEEN data_start AND IsNull(data_end, cast('1/1/9999' as datetime))
```